# Electron + React, saving file to local directory makes React reload

Tags: reactjs, electron

I'm trying to make the markdown Notepad with Electron and React(with CRA).

My plan was to write the json file for saving the file locally with fs Module, but the problem is when I try to use fs write, React recognize it as the file change and reloads the app.

And the data that should be written does not written in JSON.

So I tried react hot loader so that react stop reloading, but it does not work as I think.

I don't know why but It keeps reloading.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: You are asking 2 different questions here, split them up into separate questions. I think you answered your first question: "React recognize it as the file change and reloads the app".

Comment: Hi, if it's for storing settings like data better use library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-store . Or else you need take of created file path manually

Comment: @p2pdops thanks I'll try it